Dynamic energy of spring

Two bodies $S_1$ and $S_2$ with masses $m_2$ = $0.1\,\text{kg}$ and $m_1$ = $0.2\,\text{kg}$ respectively, are stationary on a horizontal floor. The body $S_1$ is tied to the free end of a horizontal spring of constant $k = 1450\,\text{N}/\text{m}$, whose other end is immovably fixed. Initially, the spring has its natural length and the bodies touch each other. With the help of body $S_1$, we compress the spring by $\mathrm{d}l = 0.1\,\text{m}$ and then let $S_2$ free standing. The body $S_1$ reaches its equilibrium position with speed $u_1 = 12\,\text{m}/\text{s}$ and collides centrally and elastically with the body $S_2$. Then the body $S_2$ moves on the horizontal floor. If the two bodies touch the floor with the same coefficient of friction $\mu$, calculate the coefficient of friction $\mu$.

So for the finding the coefficient of friction, I tried to use work-energy theorem. I tried to find $W_{\text{spring}}$ first with the formula $W=\Delta U=U_{\text{final}} -U_{\text{initial}}$. The final energy $U$ of the spring is $0$ because it is in its equilibrium position. The initial will be:
$\frac{1}{2}k\mathrm{d}l^2 $
So the work should be
$W_{\text{spring}}=-\frac{1}{2}k\mathrm{d}l^2$ but why is the work of the spring negative? It is the one causing the movement, shouldn't it be positive? When the body moves from the point of maximum spring compression to the equilibrium position, the force of the spring has the same direction as it's displacement, therefore the work should be positive, no?
Otherwise I'll have negative work of friction and also negative work of Fspring  which doesn't make sense to me.

Voting to reopen. Obviously a conceptual question and so allowed by policy.

Be careful to be clear about whether you are talking about the potential energy stored in the spring or the work done by the spring. A negative change in potential energy means that the spring does positive work.
When the spring is compressed by a distance $dl$ it has potential energy $\frac 1 2 k (dl)^2$. When it returns to its equilibrium position it has lost this potential energy - therefore it has done a positive amount of work $\frac 1 2 k (dl)^2$ on S1.

So i should say W=-ΔU then?

@NickTheGreek Yes.
